# howto verify that akka actor exists by name

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to send a message to an actor using the actor selection . but it keeps getting to dead letters .
This how the actor is created (using the activator template)

```
class PongActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import PongActor._

  def receive = {
    case PingActor.PingMessage(text) => 
      log.info("In PongActor - received message: {}", text)
      sender() ! PongMessage("pong")
  } 
}

object PongActor {
  val props = Props[PongActor]
  case class PongMessage(text: String)
}
```

**This is the sending actor :**

```
class PingActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import PingActor._

  var counter = 0
  val pongActor = context.actorOf(PongActor.props, "pongActor")
val tester = context.actorSelection("../pongActor") //getting the actor by name using the actorSelection 
  def receive = {
    case Initialize => 
        log.info("In PingActor - starting ping-pong")
      tester.tell(PingMessage("ping"),self)//going to dead letters
      tester ! PingMessage("ping")//also going to dead letters 
    case PongActor.PongMessage(text) =>
      log.info("In PingActor - received message: {}", text)
      counter += 1
      if (counter == 3) context.system.shutdown()
      else sender() ! PingMessage("ping")
  } 
}

object PingActor {
  val props = Props[PingActor]
  case object Initialize
  case class PingMessage(text: String)
}
```

1. why the messages are getting to the dead letters
2. how can I verify that the actor really exists ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From akka- docs

> `actorSelection` only ever looks up existing actors when messages are delivered, i.e. does not create actors, or verify existence of actors when the selection is created.

A better option is to use `resolveOne`

```
val timeout = 1.seconds
val tester1 = context.actorSelection("pongActor").resolveOne(timeout)
```

Comment: Just one correction. in context of the example above 
it should be val tester1 = context.actorSelection("pongActor").resolveOne(timeout)

Answer (score 2):

Your line `val tester = context.actorSelection("../pongActor")` is unnecessary, as the previous line sets `pongActor` to the `actorRef` you need. Just use `pongActor.tell` and `pongActor !` instead of `tester.tell` and `tester !`.

As for why the `actorSelection` lookup is failing: when you create a child actor inside a parent actor (here `Ping` is the parent, `Pong` is the child), the path to the child is the same as the path to the parent, with the child's name appended. So, relative to `Ping`, the path to `Pong` is just "pongActor", not "../pongActor".

Comment: Thank you . as for the 1st part of your answer. I deliberately wanted to check the use of actorSelection as a demo . as for the second part - it is very helpful - thanks !!!